# Why don't n-1 for df in this scenario

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

Simple statistics question, but can't figured out.

> What is the critical value t* for constructing a 99%, percent confidence interval for a mean with 11 degrees of freedom?

My answer for this is 3.169 where df = 10 and two tails' value is 0.01

But the correct answer is 3.106 where df = 11.

I am confused why we don't minus 1 here for df.

Don't we df = n -1 where n is the sample size?

Comment: Where in the question is the sample size mentioned? I see only that it tells you how many degrees of freedom there are. Why should you disbelieve what is written in the question?

Comment: @DavidK, this is all I have for the question. There is no additonal information given:(

Comment: It says "with $11$ degrees of freedom". Therefore you have $11$ degrees of freedom. Not $10.$

Comment: @DavidK, Ohhh, just realized that  degrees of freedom is df (sorry stupid question). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help :-)